# Name attribute on the <wsdl:definitions> tag

Tags: wcf, service, wsdl

I am writing a WCF service and need to control the value of the name atttribute on the wsdl:definitions tag in the generated WSDL document. The ServiceBehavior and the ServiceContract attributes do nothave any property on them that dictates the output value of the name in the definitions tag. Changing the service implementation class name does not make a difference either. Any help is appreciated.

#### EDIT:

The `ServiceBehavior` **Name** named parameter translates directly into both the **wsdl:definitions** element's **name** attribute value and the **wsdl:service** element's **name** attribute value. In WCF, is there a way to assign a different value to the **wsdl:definitions** element's **name** attribute?

```
[ServiceBehavior(Name = "FooService", 
                 Namespace = "http://foo.bar/2011/01/", 
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, 
                 InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class FooService: IFooService
{
     //etc...
}
```

becomes:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="FooService" ... >
```

and

```
<wsdl:service name="FooService">
```

How can I make the **wsdl:definitions** element's **name** attribute value be "FooDefinition"?

Comment: http://sscce.org/ - tell us exactly what you're trying to do and how with an example. we should fix the example

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560914/wcf-web-service-change-wsdl-name-and-targetnamespace